# json encode and replacement for JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Tags: php, arrays, json

Since I cant use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` because my php is < 5.4, I have tried some replacements from [`json_encode()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$final = array (
  0 => array (
    'id' => 26629,
    'content' => 'преди 5 сек'
  ),
  1 => array (
    'id' => 26628,
    'content' => 'преди 5 сек'
  ),
  2 => array (
    'id' => 26627,
    'content' => 'преди 5 сек'
  )
);

$myDirtyString = json_encode($final);
$myDirtyString = str_replace("\/","/",$myDirtyString);
$myDirtyString = str_replace('"','\\"',$myDirtyString);

echo $myCleanedString = json_decode('"'.$myDirtyString.'"');
```

And the result is:

```
[
  {"id":"26629","timestamp":"преди 5 сек"},
  {"id":"26628","timestamp":"преди 5 сек"},
  {"id":"26625","timestamp":"¿ÑÐµÐ´Ð¸ 5 ÑÐµÐº"}
]
```

Why the last item is such a mess?

I tried

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

...but still dosent work.

Comment: The last item in the Array you posted is : `'id' => 26627`, but the last item in the printout is `"id":"26625"`, so it seems like there are 2 different arrays... Is the printout 1-to-1 exact to what you're trying to do?

Comment: The json produced without `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is perfectly valid. Why bother trying to tidy it up?

Comment: I ran your code without anything extra, and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If your on a version of PHP before 5.4, this might help:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    function json_encode($data) {
        switch ($type = gettype($data)) {
            case 'NULL':
                return 'null';
            case 'boolean':
                return ($data ? 'true' : 'false');
            case 'integer':
            case 'double':
            case 'float':
                return $data;
            case 'string':
                return '"' . addslashes($data) . '"';
            case 'object':
                $data = get_object_vars($data);
            case 'array':
                $output_index_count = 0;
                $output_indexed = array();
                $output_associative = array();
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $output_indexed[] = json_encode($value);
                    $output_associative[] = json_encode($key) . ':' . json_encode($value);
                    if ($output_index_count !== NULL && $output_index_count++ !== $key) {
                        $output_index_count = NULL;
                    }
                }
                if ($output_index_count !== NULL) {
                    return '[' . implode(',', $output_indexed) . ']';
                } else {
                    return '{' . implode(',', $output_associative) . '}';
                }
            default:
                return ''; // Not supported
        }
    }
}
?>
```